# How to tell fluentd to filter logs based on "logger_name" field?

Tags: logging, logback, fluentd

My code issues structured logs, which contain a `logger_name` field. These logs are later sent to some remote logging storage via `fluentd`. I'd like fluentd to filter logs coming from Kafka streams library. Tried this configuration, but it did not work:

```
<filter containers.**>
  @type grep
  <exclude>
    key logger_name
    pattern /org.apache.kafka.streams/
  </exclude>
</filter>
```

I'm using `logback`, and AFAIK, it's in charge of adding the `logger_name` field, so I think it's safe to assume that when `fluentd` sees the logs, they already contain this field.

What could be the reason the filter is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not in the syntax, but rather in the pattern field:

```
pattern /org.apache.kafka.streams/
```

The `.` should be escaped, making the correct pattern:

```
pattern /org\.apache\.kafka\.streams/
```

After adding the missing `\`, the filter worked as expected.